# How to attach a youtube video to a card in the timeline of my glassware

Tags: python, google-mirror-api

i'm struggling to find a way to deliver youtube video in the glassware i'm developing using python.
What i want to do is to push a card to the users of my glassware and attach to it a youtube video.
The problem is that , judging from the online documentation, you can only attach a video to the card by uploading it from your server to the google mirror apis.
I was not able to find any method to link the video in the card.
(https://developers.google.com/glass/timeline#attaching_video)

I also tried to embed the iframe html code in the card but both the iframe and video tags are stripped out so ... no cigar.

I also thought about pushing the card in the user's timeline and put a link in the card html. The problem is that the link in the card is not clickable from the user.
Neither can i add an action to the card since actions seems not able to open external links.
(https://developers.google.com/glass/menu-items)

I'm running out of ideas....

Any suggestion or lateral thinking approaches will be greatly appreciated

F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attaching YouTube videos to timeline items and allowing users to click on links in timeline items are not features in the Mirror API and Glass.

You can file a feature request [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list). It is helpful to describe your use case.